# controller Action not working in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

i am using zend framework 1.12.3.

index.php :

```
    switch(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
      case '/admin/':  
        define('APPLICATION_PATH',
        realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application/admin'));
      break;
      case '/store/':  
        define('APPLICATION_PATH',
        realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application/stoe'));
      break;
      default:  
        define('APPLICATION_PATH',
        realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application/store'));
      break;
    }
```

Admin controller :

```
    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */

    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
      $request = $this->getRequest();  

      $this->view->assign('title', 'Login Form');
      $this->view->assign('username', 'User Name'); 
      $this->view->assign('password', 'Password');
    }


    public function authAction()
    {
       echo 'test';exit;    
    }
```

when i access the url:
http://pro.localhost/admin/ - this is working

but when i access the url :
http://pro.localhost/admin/auth
showing error 'Page not found' and 'Message: Invalid controller specified (admin) '

Comment: show your .htaccess file

Comment: Have you got a related view file auth.phtml in place for the AuthAction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` isn't ***equal*** to '/admin/' when you visit '/admin/auth/', so APPLICATION_PATH is being defined as the store path instead.  You should be checking for whether `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` ***begins*** with '/admin/'.  And you shouldn't need a switch statement to check two conditions.

```
if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), '/admin/') === 0) {
    define(
        'APPLICATION_PATH',
        realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application/admin')
    );
} else {
    define(
        'APPLICATION_PATH',
         realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application/store')
    );
}
```